# A way to extract certain <p> tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm stuck on a current problem extracting the text from a p tag using BS4.

For reference purposes, linked is a screenshot of the HTML.
[image]

What I need to extract is specifically the p tag that contains the text, but there are other p tags that exist.

What I currently have is:

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2, 'html.parser')
div = soup2.find("div", {"id": "body"}).find_all('p')
print (div[5])
```

I understand that the find_all creates a list of all p tags, and I could potentially find the list index of the p tag I'm looking for.  However, that presents a problem since I'm performing this extraction multiple times on other pages with a similar HTML layout as in the picture.  As in, not every find_all list will have the p tag text I'm looking for as the 5th index.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The `<p>` element in your screenshot has no identifying feature, i.e. no class or id or any other attribute. So how do you determine which `<p>` element you want if it's not always the 5th index? Is it always the one after the `<p>` element that has "Last statement:" as the text?

Comment: If I could express it another way, when you look at any one of these documents what feature of the page is it that identifies the paragraph you want?

Answer (score 0):

find_all accepts many arguments.

you can use them to better filter the results.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

you can also iterate over all the elements and find the most likely one.

create a sample of 100 html pages, and find a method/mix of strategies that works for all of them.